# Set class type of $this in included file from class

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I have a standard mvc thing going on of my own design.

In it I have template files I render in which the controller class can be referenced via $this for certain functions to render different views etc...

In my view I have code like this:

```
<img  alt="<?= $record->image ? $record->image->description:'' ?>"
      src="<?= $record->image ? $this->getImagePath($record->image):'' ?>">
```

Is there a way in eclipse to set the type of the `$this` object when it's used in this way for code completion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place at the head of your included file a comment like this

```
<?php
/**
 * @var $this \Lib\TourTripRender
 */
?>
```

Now the $this should autocomplete properly